# Regex expression returns nothing. Why?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, escaping

This returns nothing?

```
# Enter your code for "Image Extractor" here.
import re
with open('site.html') as html:
    content = html.read()
    content = str(content)
    print(re.findall(r'<ima?ge?\s+[^>]*?src=["|\']([^["|\']]+)', content))
```

I think it has something to do with me escaping the backslash from the expression...

Comment: What's the value of `content`?

Comment: Do you have an example of the text you are trying to match?

Answer (score 2):

```
[^["|\']]
```

I'm not sure what you wanted this to do. You can't nest character classes or use `|` for alternation in a character class. The way you have it now, this section matches any character that isn't one of the following:

```
[
"
|
'
```

followed by a literal `]`. If you wanted this to be a single character class that matches anything but a single or double quote, you wanted

```
[^"\']
```